# Is there a way to prevent keyboard macros from running on a program?

Tags: c++, macros

I've developed an online game, sadly there's a select few people who are using recorded keyboard macros using programs like Razer Synapse to automate part of the game process.

This is something I'd like to not allow.

So my question is, is there a way in C++ to determine if a macro is being used to preform input or to determine if the most recent key click triggered was triggered by a human input or programmed input?

My first guess is no... but I could be wrong.

Comment: All you might guess is the maximum typing speed of a human. Anything else is a machine. On the other hand, hackers are clever and adopt.

Comment: @DieterLücking yes, but in this instance... They're using a recorded macro that records the users input at the same speeds... I suppose I could track each players input times... But the amount of players and amount of times they use this type of input... Would be too much...

Comment: An idea might be making fuzzy unreliable input (e.g.:some random failures of a weapon) a part of the game (it has to be enjoyable, though)

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about the situation? Is there a dedicated client binary "under your control"?

Comment: How long are these macros typically (how many keystrokes)?

Comment: The macros typically consist of 1-3 keys at a time (usually number keys). As I understand it, the users are just recording there normal human keystrokes using programs like Razer Synapse. So these types of macros already bypass my server side macro detection because it is still humanly possible (it's not spamming the keys a huge amount of times at once).

I have access to the client code in c++.

Comment: There's a reason huge companies like Blizzard still have to deal with this on a daily basis. Anything on the client is out of your control, any defense mechanism you put into the client can be removed from that client. Any mechanism you put into the server can be worked around. You can make it harder for players to cheat but never impossible.

Comment: If your players don't even get a speedup out of their keyboard macros, then their use of the keyboard macros only means one thing: Your game-user-interface is too user-unfriendly. I think, you should take the hint for these "cheaters": Look at *what* stuff they are typically merging into keyboard macros, and build features into your game that allow them to do their stuff with your own code. This lifts your game onto a higher abstraction level, and I guess, it will make it more interesting.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot prevent automation from any client you don't control. The study of algorithms is hundreds of years old, and computers are intended first to be devices of automation. Whatever novelty you come up with will be easily defeated simply because somebody was up to the challenge. That does not mean to say you should avoid solutions which assure bots aren't given a significant advantage, such as speed of input as suggested in the above comments, but if you hope to stop automation altogether you are climbing an endlessly steep hill.

Maybe you should evaluate and consider if rampant automation is an indicator that some aspect of your game mechanics are being viewed as, well, boring. We should strive to provide a player with enough stimulation to want to remain engaged in our games.

Comment: "We should strive to provide a player with enough stimulation to want to remain engaged in our games." Some players just dont want to work for progression and will let bots do the dirty work, no matter how engaged you keep them.

Comment: @GillBates Programming a bot to play a game is a valid hobby in and of itself ;-) Of course, it gets problematic if the bots either pawn the humans or allow some players to get an unfair advantage over other players by transferring stuff from bot accounts to human accounts. But this does not seem to be the case in this question: The question is about keyboard macros, which are only tools for a player to make their interaction with the game more high-level. And that is indeed a sign for the game-user-interface being too low-level/repetitive/boring.